# Unable to parse ISO 8601 dates in PHP 4 using strtotime

Tags: php, php4, strtotime

I'm trying to parse the following [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) date in PHP 4 using the [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function:

```
2012-02-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

However this returns -1.  How come and what can I do to work around this?

Unfortunately I'm stuck using PHP 4.3.10 and so can't use any of the newer functions to parse dates.

Comment: Not helpful, but: PHP 5 has been out for nearly 8 years now. Probably time to unstick yourself :P

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
strtotime(str_replace('T', ' ', $date));
```

Comment: This still returns -1. Some experimentation reveals that it parses the string `2012-02-01T00:00:00`, I'm just not sure how to detect that the date is in that format.

Answer (score 1):

That works for me:

```
$iso = '2013-06-25T15:16:13.000Z';
$d = str_replace('T', ' ', $iso);
$d = substr($d, 0, 19);
$ts = strtotime($d);

$isIso =  (strlen($iso) == 24 && substr($iso, 10, 1) === "T" && substr($iso, 19, 1) === "." && substr($iso, 23, 1) === "Z");
```